# Find Noether normalization of a ring - verify my solution.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A=\Bbb C[x,y,z,t]/I$ where $I=(x^2 +xy-z,xy^2-t^2+z,x^2y+xy^2+t^2)$.

Find the Noether Normalization of A.

My solution:

We are looking for new variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$. I found:

$x\mapsto x_1$

$y\mapsto -x_1$

$t\mapsto x_2$

$z\mapsto x_3$

New variables are independent - important.

Then, our generators of ideal go to $(x_3,-x_1^3-x_2^2+x_3,x_2^2)$, so vanishing set of them is set $\{ z=0, t=0, (xy=0)\}$. So under that coordinate change, ring $A$ goes to $\Bbb C[x,y]/(xy)$, which is a direct sum of $\Bbb C[x]$ and $\Bbb C[y]$.

So, is the Noether Normalization of $A$, $\Bbb C[x,y]/(xy)$???

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: In the future, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset mathematical formulas. This will make your post much more readable.

Comment: $\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy)$ is not a direct sum of $\mathbb C[x]$ and $\mathbb C[y]$. You can try to find out all idempotent elements in $\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy)$.

Comment: This is not even a solution to the proposed problem: the Noether Normalization is a map from a _single_ polynomial ring $\Bbb C[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to A$ which make $A$ in to a finite $\Bbb C[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ algebra. Your answer is incomplete (you're missing the map) and your ring $\Bbb C[x,y]/(xy)$ is not a polynomial ring.

Comment: @KReiser so what should I do?

Comment: @KReiser so map C[x,y]->A=C[x,y]/(xy) - it is Noether Normalization?

Comment: @MaciejFicek you should reread what Noether normalization claims to do: for a fg $k$-algebra $A$, it's an injection from $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to A$ for some $n$ which makes $A$ finite over $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. In particular, $n=\dim A$. This shows that your second comment about $\Bbb C[x,y]\to \Bbb C[x,y]/(xy)$ can't be something produced by Noether normalization: the target is of dimension 1, but the source is of dimension 2.

Comment: @KReiser could You give me hint how to to that exercise from the start, forgetting everything I wrote here? There are almost 0 examples of Noether Normalization exercises in Google, and these which are, are much easier.

Comment: @MaciejFicek I've posted an answer - it's may not be quite as "hint"-y as you might like, but given your effort I thought being a little clearer would help more.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments, the material in the post is not a solution. Here's an approach which does produce a solution.

Step 1: We can rewrite $\Bbb C[x,y,z,t]/(x^2+xy-z,xy^2-t^2+z,x^2y+xy^2+t^2)$ as a ring with no $z$ by replacing $z=x^2+xy$ everywhere it appears. Specifically, $\Bbb C[x,y,t]/(xy^2+x^2+xy-t^2,x^2y+xy^2+t^2)$ is isomorphic to our original ring by the map which sends $x,y,t$ to themselves and $z\mapsto x^2+xy$.

Step 2: We can rewrite the ideal $(xy^2+x^2+xy-t^2,x^2y+xy^2+t^2)$ as $(x^2y+2xy^2+x^2+xy,x^2y+xy^2+t^2)$, which shows us that the projection from the variety of this ideal to the curve given by $V(x^2y+2xy^2+x^2+xy)\subset \Bbb A^2$ is 2-to-1 (In algebraic terms, this corresponds to the fact that $\Bbb C[x,y,t]/(x^2y+2xy^2+x^2+xy,x^2y+xy^2+t^2)$ is a finite $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^2y+2xy^2+x^2+xy)$ module with basis $\{1,t\}$.) So all we need to do is find a Noether normalization of this and we're in business.

Step 3: the equation $x^2y+2xy^2+x^2+xy$ factors as $x(2y^2+xy+y+x)$, so the variety it cuts out is the union of the $y$-axis and a conic. We can see easily from the equation of this conic that the projection on to the $y$-axis is 2-to-1, using the same reasoning as in step 2. The projection of the $y$-axis to the $y$-axis is the identity, so the projection from the curve $V(x^2y+2xy^2+x^2+xy)$ to the $y$-axis is finite.

Now we put it all together. By composing steps 1, 2, and 3, we get a map from our original curve on to $\Bbb A^1$ which is finite: it's the composition of an isomorphism and two finite maps. Tracing what this means on coordinate algebras, we get that the map $\Bbb C[y]\to \Bbb C[x,y,z,t]/I$ by $y\mapsto y$ is a Noether normalization of this ring.